# Abstract algebra: finding order or group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Find the order of a group defined by: 
       $$G=\{u,v\,|\,u^4=v^3=1,\,u\cdot v=u^2\cdot v^2\}.$$

When I first looked at the problem it looked like dihedral group but it's not. I am unable to find order of group.

Comment: I suspect there is a mistake in this presentation. You wouldn't normally write a relation as $uv=u^2v^2$ since that is equivalent to $uv=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Indeed, but would a beginner notice it right away?

Answer (score 6):

Since $uv=u^2v^2\Longleftrightarrow uv=uuvv\Longleftrightarrow 1=vu$, $G$ is generated both by $u$ and bt $v$ (since each one is the inverse of the other one). But then $u^4=u^3=1$. So $u=1$. Therefore, $|G|=1$.

Comment: @johnnobody No. How do you jump from $u^7=1$ to $|G|=7$? From $u^7=1$ you can't deduce that the smallest $n$ such that $u^n=1$ is $7$.